# Javscript: No double quote before the opening bracket and after the last bracket

Tags: javascript

The issue is related to the extra double quotes **"** character in the products array in between the opening **[** and the first **{** , as well as between the closing **}** and **]** , this comes from the JavaScript variable called "products" being printed as a string.
So the question is how to get that variable to print without the surrounding double quotes?

```
let products = '';
        for(var i=0; i<this.items.length; i++) {
            products += "{";
            products += "'name'    : '" + this.items[i].info.brand + " " + this.items[i].info.title + "',";
            products += "'id'    : '" + this.items[i].info.sku + "',";
            products += "'price'    : '" + this.items[i].info.price + "',";
            products += "'brand'    : '" + this.items[i].info.brand + "',";
            products += "'category'    : '" + this.items[i].info.category + "',";
            products += "'variant'    : '" + this.items[i].info.color + "',";
            products += "'quantity'    : '" + this.items[i].quantity + "',";
            products += "}";
            if(i != (this.items.length - 1)){
                products += ',';
            }
            console.log(products);
        }
```

So when I print the products, you can see the entire products section is within double quotes. What I am trying to do is there should be no double quote before the opening bracket of the first product, and after the last bracket of the last product.

[image]

Comment: There isn't a double quote there. It's just how the console displays strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are trying to build an object, in which case you should just use `.map` on `this.items`, e.g.:

```js
function example() {
  return { products: this.items.map((item) => {
      return {
          "name": item.info.brand + " " + item.info.title,
          "id": item.info.sku,
          "price": item.info.price,
          "brand": item.info.brand,
          "category": item.info.category,
          "variant": item.info.color,
          "quantity": item.info.quantity
      };
  })};
}

console.log(
    example.bind({ items: [{info: { brand: "whirlpool", title: "dishwasher", sku: "123", price: "$140", category: "dishwashers", color: "white", quantity: 2}}]})()
)
```